# Odd multicast messages during IPv6 autoconfiguration

Tags: ipv6, multicast, configuration

So I am trying a little autoconfiguration on some virtual machines while observing what happens in wireshark and trying to understand what how it works, step by step.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MARR5.jpg) is how any of those captures looks. I can see the router solicitation and advertisement, as well as the DAD packages. However, there is always a bunch of Multicast Listener Report Messages, and I have not been able to figure out their purpose.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1FK6.jpg) are how this packets look.

I have tried googling around but I have not found any answers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC 4862](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4862.txt):

> 5.4.2.  Sending Neighbor Solicitation Messages
>
> Before sending a Neighbor Solicitation, an interface MUST join the 
>   all-nodes multicast address and the solicited-node multicast address
>   of the tentative address.